# Not able to see TestNG in libraries in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I am trying to add TestNG in Eclipse. I installed/uninstalled multiple times but still not able to get TestNG under "Run As". When I look under installed software, it shows TestNG there but no where else it's listed like Add Library and other places. Please help.

I am using MAC mini OS X Yosemite version 10.10 and eclipse luna 4.4.2

Comment: Are you sure you are right clicking the package where tests files are locating? Maybe you are right clicking the entire project.

Comment: Yes am very sure. TestNG is not getting listed in Add library or any other place as well. I saw in my friends machine.. they followed the same steps and for them TestNG is available under Package explorer. But not for me :(

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse just starting acting weird....my Ant Views and Ant task all gone after installing TestNG....dono the reason....

Comment: I was able to see testNG finally. Issue was jdk. We need to use jdk 7 and above for testNG and I had jdk 6 on my mac.